# How to let tmux know which shell runs in current pane?

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

I would like my tmux status bar to show what shell is currently running in the active pane if possible. For the record, I use Ubuntu Server 18.04.

I've thought about using the variable #{pane_pid} to get the PID of the shell that was opened with the pane, and retrieve the name from that.

However, this wouldn't work if you started a subshell in the current pane or used sudo su and that changed the shell. In this case I would like tmux to know the name of the "latest" shell that was run in the pane.

Is there any way this information can be retrieved? Preferably using tmux variables, alternatively with a script (or combination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `#{pane_current_command}` doesn't work well enough (it won't be able to across `su`) you will need to write your own script.

I recommend using `ps -t #{pane_tty}` rather than `#{pane_pid}` which will be more reliable.

Working out which process is the "best" one from a list of multiple running processes is not necessarily easy but if you just want shells you can probably make it work.

The other thing you could do is have the shell set the title by doing something like:

```
printf "\033]2;$SHELL\033\\"
```

In `PS1`, then you can get that for the pane in `#{pane_title}`.

Or have the shell just run `[ -n "$TMUX" ] && tmux selectp -T $SHELL` if you are always on localhost.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into it.

Comment: I like the solution with the shell setting the pane title, since it can then also figure out its version number and other stuff that I want to set and display "per shell".